# Flex compiler warning - variable 'item' has no type declaration

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex-builder-3

I am tyring to learn flex programming myself. Below code gives me a warning

> > variable 'item' has no type declaration.

```
var xml:XML = xml as XML;

for each (var item in xml.employee) {
    Alert.show(item.@name); 
}
```

What is the type of variable **item**? I thought it was XMLNode, but it give me error. I want to remove the compile warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this please, you haven't initialized item.

```
var xml:XML = new XML();

for each (var item:XML in xml.employee) {
    Alert.show(item.@name); 
}
```